# Resize image biggen, and keep pixel-like quality

Tags: c#, image

I am currently resizing a few images into a bigger size for a pixel coloring game, I have the entire process of down-scaling and reducing the amount of colors down, and i want to save every image to a file, so that I can use it.

For that purpose, it is useful to have the image be bigger when it is imported, but when I try to scale up the image to a bigger size, the result is very blurry, and adds more colors, and I want it to keep it's pixelated format.

What I want to end up with specifically is an image of a bigger size, that loos the exact same. Width and Height both increase at the same amount, so a pixel should become a 2 x 2 box with the same color if the image is scaled up by a margin of 2.

how do i do this?

I am using this code to size down images, so i can pixelate them.

```
public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Image image, int width, int height)
{
    // Set the size of the required image and the size to take from the source
    var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

    // Set the resolution correct
    destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
    {
        // Make sure the quality is good
        graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

        using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
        {
            // resize the image
            wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
            graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
        }
    }

    return destImage;
}
```

what changes do I need to make to it to make a method that keeps pixilation upon sizing up?

Comment: I think you should use `SmoothingMode.None` and `InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor`.